# API-method can return different types, how do i define the return type?

Tags: java, spring

```
I have the following API method:

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<Project>> getProjects(@RequestParam(required = false) String userName, @RequestParam(required = false) boolean additionalInfo) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(projectService.getProjects(userName, additionalInfo));
  }
```

It currently returns `ResponseEntity<List<Project>>`. But if the optional paramater `additionalInfo` is true, i would like to return `ResponseEntity<List<ProjectAdditionalInfoDTO>>`. How do i define the return type to indicate that both of them can be returned? Of course i could use `ResponseEntity<?>`, but that would be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep things simple and just split things up into two separate controller methods... e.g.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<Project>> getProjects(@RequestParam(required=false) String userName) {
    //...
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<ProjectAdditionalInfoDTO>> getProjectsWithAdditionalInfos(@RequestParam(required=false) String userName, @RequestParam(required=true) boolean additionalInfo) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: But the problem is, if `additionalInfo` is false, i would stlil like to return `Project` instead of `ProjectAdditionalInfoDTO`.

Answer (score 0):

If they both have the same interface (let's say BaseProject) you can make it return the following:

```
ResponseEntity<List<? extends BaseProject>>
```

There is no possibility to show that 2 options are possible in the return type via the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand ProjectAdditionalInfoDTO should inherit Project. That means that if you add inheritance there, then you can return the parent class  since ProjectAdditionalInfoDTO  would always be Project. If not, then since they are different resources you should have different endpoints to access them.